# Two martingales with respect to the same filtration

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, expectation

> Let $(X_n)_{n\ge1}$ and $(Y_n)_{n\ge1}$ be two martingales with respect to the same
>   filtration $(\mathcal{F}_n)_{n\ge1}$. Suppose that $E[\lvert X_n\rvert]<\infty$ and
>   $E[\lvert Y_n\rvert]<\infty$ for every $n\ge1$.

How do I prove the following assertions?

> > (1) $E[X_nY_n]-[X_1Y_1]=\sum\limits_{k=2}^n E[(X_k-X_{k-1})(Y_k-Y_{k-1})]$
> >
> > (2) The random variables $X_1$, $X_k-X_{k-1}$, $k\ge2$, are pairwise orthogonal.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try anything? Say, to prove (1) by induction?

Comment: I did. In the inductive step I get $E(X_nY_n)-E(X_1Y_1)+E(X_{n+1}Y_{n+1})-E(X_{n+1}Y_n)-E(X_nY_{n+1})+E(X_nY_n)$ and I don't know how to continue. I guess I need to use the fact that $(X_n)$, $(Y_n)$ are martingales,but I don't know how.

Comment: This inductive step needs correction. To go from $n$ to $n+1$, no $E[X_1Y_1]$ is involved.

Comment: But I assumed that the property holds for n and then I wrote $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n+1} E((X_k-X_{k-1})(Y_k-Y_{k-1}))=E(X_nY_n)-E(X_1Y_1)+E((X_{n+1}-X_n)(Y_{n+1}-Y_n))$.

Comment: Yes, and one should check that this equals...?

Comment: $E(X_{n+1}Y_{n+1})-E(X_1Y_1)$

Comment: Yes, hence at least one term can be simplified on both sides and you are left with an identity to prove. Can you write down this identity?

Comment: So I have to show that $2E(X_nY_n)-E(X_{n+1}Y_n)-E(X_nY_{n+1})=0$, right? My problem is, I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Apply twice the hint in my answer.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't get it. Which hint do you mean?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

> Let $\mathcal G$ denote a sigma-algebra and $\xi$ and $\eta$ some integrable random variables such that $\eta$ is measurable with respect to $\mathcal G$.
>
> Then $E[\xi\eta\mid\mathcal G]=\zeta\eta$, where $\zeta=E[\xi\mid\mathcal G]$. In particular, $E[\xi\eta]=E[\zeta\eta]$.

Comment: Okay, now I get it. Thank you!

Comment: Could you maybe also give me a hint for (2)?

Comment: Surely you can try at least a liiiittle bit to apply the hint to (2) as well, no?